# How to open windows with 85 characters width

Tags: window, aquamacs

Newbie question

In my Preferences.el file there is a line
(setq-default fill-column 78)
which works wonderfully.

Now I need to tell Emacs (Aqumacs in my case) to open windows
with 85 characters width, so that I do not have to resize every 
window when it opens (as they open with around 60 characters width only).

How do I do that?

Comment: Do you really mean (Emacs) window or (Emacs) frame? A window typically has the width of its frame, or else a width that results from dividing an existing window left/right.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to set the default **frame** width, then just customize option `default-frame-alist` to specify parameter `width` as `85`:

```
M-x customize-option RET default-frame-alist RET
```

Save your customization.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved using

```
(setq default-frame-alist
              '(
                (width . 140)
                ))
```

85 did not work, probably because the number is font-dependent.

Comment: That is the *same answer* I already gave: **Use `default-frame-alist`.** But what you say about 85 not working is not clear to me. Just what does "*85 did not work*" mean - what are the symptoms? It works for me. And what do you mean by "*the number is font-dependent*"? The frame `width` parameter is the number of characters, regardless of the face/font used.

Comment: Perhaps the user is changing the font subsequent to creating the frame, and that is why 140 seems to work better.  The font can be set simultaneously as part of the `default-frame-alist`.  Note:  there were several bugs prior to feature 21415 that previously prevented proper frame creation (fonts, sizes, positioning) -- Emacs 25 and master branch have the bug fixes implemented.

Comment: My experience is also that the number does not properly translate to the number of columns in the created frame. Perhaps the width is calculated in a different font than the one the frame actually ends up using?